# Fast RTRL(Real Time Recurrent Learning) for RNN

Tags: backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network

Assume generic RNN has update formula:

$\mathbf{h}_{t+1} = f(\mathbf{x_t},\mathbf{h_t},\mathbf{\theta})$ [1]

Where $\mathbf{x}$ is input vector, $\mathbf{h}$ is hidden state vector, and $\theta$ is network parameters.

In RTRL,one need to maintain gradient (or jacobian matrix) of $\mathbf{h}$ w.r.t $\mathbf{\theta}$ at each step of iteration.

$G_{t+1} = \frac{\partial f(x_t,h_t,\theta)}{\partial h}G_t+\frac{\partial f(x_t,h_t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ [2]

Since $G$ often takes $O(n^3)$ memory ($n$ is number of hidden units), plus expensive GEMMs, RTRL in this form is rarely used in practical applications.

Instead of using approximation methods like [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07680), **is it possible to design a $f$ such that equation [2] is fast to compute?** Preferably no need to maintain $G$ at all.

For example, if certain $f$ satisfies:

$\frac{\partial f(x_t,h_t,\theta)}{\partial h}G_t=\lambda \frac{\partial f(x_t,h_t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ [3]

Then there would be no need to maintain $G$ at all.
Intuitively, the memory of such RNN should contain complete information to compute full gradient for all previous timesteps. This will allow RNN to be trained with one-step-backpropagation.

**UPDATE:**

For univariete case ($x$, $h$, $\theta$ are scalars), the following function satisfies [3]:

$f(x,h,\theta) = c_1(x,\theta) h^{c_2(x,\theta)}$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are differentiable function w.r.t $x$ and $\theta$.

This seems to suggest a "perfect memory" RNN should take power function form.

I'm not a mathematician, I'm not sure what's the best way to extend this result to multivariete case while handling long term dependence well.